# Regular Expression look ahead in log

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, logparser

https://regex101.com/r/9kfa7D/4

I can never get the look ahead portion correct. I've tried a few different things, but I'm trying to get to the next date and parse it like that. Mainly because I don't know what the message will look like and it could be pretty random. Any help would be great.

I need to group the message portion of it.

Edit: Updated to make it a little more clear of what I'm trying to do. Never everything from each date.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/w4ydX4/1

Comment: @Faibbus exactly what i am looking for. Would you be able to explain it? I always have a hard time learning how to do a look ahead.

Answer (score 2):

You can just tweak your regex without tinkering lookahead like this:

```
^\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} (?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{3}
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9kfa7D/3)

---

**EDIT:**

As per updated question OP can use this negative lookahead based regex to capture log text:

```
^[^\[]+\[[^\]]+\] +[^:]+ +(.*(?:\n(?!\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-).*)*)
```

This regex doesn't use `DOTALL` flag by unrolling the loop in last segment. This makes above regex pretty fast to complete the parsing.

[New Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9kfa7D/8)

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. I need the message portion of it.

Comment: In this case, you can split on @anubhava's pattern.

Comment: It's not proper expression, it will halt if line starts with two digits at the beginning of a new line and it happens, the message actually contains such sequence. Instead it should check for the signature of new log entry. Assumption that 2 digits at the beginning of a new line will do is just incorrect.

Comment: Check my updated regex now that is pretty fast and efficient.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's much faster. But scroll down to the end of parsed text — it doesn't match correctly the message, unfortunately.

Comment: I have scrolled down to the last matched log message. Be specific on what you think it is not matching correctly.

Comment: I can't place screenshot in the comment, but look carefully at the end: in matched Group 1 there's only `SessionListener: contextDestroyed()` but the previous part of the message, `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log`, belongs to Full match and it is not the part of Group 1 (but it should).

Comment: That's not correct. [Check this demo again](https://regex101.com/r/9kfa7D/9) Just before first `SessionListener: contextDestroyed()` there is very long match that ends with `:8843` and that is correctly shown in `Group 1.`

Comment: Look at Match 12 (85499-85639) in MATCH INFORMATION frame and see what goes into Group 1. Examine carefully Full match of Match 12 (the end of it) and see for yourself, that java package part didn't go into Group 1, but it should.

Comment: oh I see :) That is not just in 12th match, that is in every match. My regex is just capturing log message that comes after Java package name. If OP wants to capture package name as well then regex can be reduced to [`^[^\[]+\[[^\]]+\] +(.*(?:\n(?!\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-).*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/9kfa7D/10)

Answer (score 0):

`^(?:\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} (?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{3}) ((?:[^\n]+(?:\n+(?!\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4})|))+)`

The first part is the date pattern, which is non-grouping since you do not want to keep the date.

The second part is `[^\n]+` which is followed by a `\n` provided it is not followed by `\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}` (hence the negative look ahead).

The second part is then repeated any number of times.

You can see the demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/w4ydX4/2).

Comment: You must count on the luck for the `\d{2}-` to not to appear in the message, thou. A bit unstable.

Comment: You're right, I'm gonna make a longer negative lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

If you care for the message between log timestamps use this (it's in the 2-nd group):

`/(\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \S+ \S+ \[[^\]]++\] )(?=(.+)((?1)|\z))/gms`

Comment: Both `++` and `(?1)` (recursion) are PCRE constructs. It won't work in Javascript or Python or Java. OP hasn't mentioned anywhere about PCRE. Even with PCRE this is awfully slow performing regex.

Comment: Just as you said, there were no constraints on regex class and because the text to parse looked more like a log, then I implicitly assumed there is no real need to throw away convenient method. Don't know much about Python, but possessive quantifiers (`++`) actually work in Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html). Not sure as to subroutines (`(?1)`). Some languages use also different syntax (as in Ruby). And yes, it's not light-speed fast, but it does the work properly. There's always room for improvement.

Comment: @Faibbus To be perfectly honest, I didn't know about it also until yesterday. ;-) I just wondered if there is a way to specify a pattern once and use it again in other part of the expression and I found out it is actually possible. 8) I rather try to solve problems that force me to learn something new, than just to lookup for an answer in the past experience. 8) And by the way I also learned about atomic groups that can reduce backtracking. I consider this investigation as well spent time. 8)

Answer (score 0):

**What you need**
`(^\d+.[A-Z].*?)[A-Z]`

**how it works**
Lots of people like the complex thinking when they are confront a regex. But you should know exactly what you want.

you just need to match this: `29-Jun-2016 09:33:43.565 INFO` and nothing else. So let's begin:

First: `two digit,`
next: `A word with capital letter`
next: `everything from this word to the next capitalize word`
finish.

**the main rule**
Non-greedy mantch:  `.*?`

### [prove](https://regex101.com/r/7a5YJb/1)

---

**NOTE**
do you want to match from beginning to `log`
very easy just add `.*?log` at the end. that's it.

**Do you ever pay attention to how many steps it take?**

[image]

First of mine: 7952
Second of mine:   13751
Compare it with other

> After putting the picture here. some guys **update** their regex. I do
>   not want to **argue**. no problem. I just wanted to show it. 
>   Otherwise I can ( as you can ) makes it less by choice the specific
>   **pattern**   For example:   `^\d+-[A-Za-z]+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+`   Now `7952` become `3878`

Do you want to learn how **lock-head** assertion works?
Very easy. The main concept is that `(?=)` is never matches anything. It only matches the **position** just **one** point before you want.
like:
`^\d+-[A-Z].+(?=[A-Z]+ ).`
It still matches: `29-Jun-2016 09:33:43.565 INFO`
Pay attention to `.` at the end.  So here the look head assertion **point** to between `F` and `O`

If would like to match this `29-Jun-2016 09:33:43.565` then **what can you do?**
Think about this:
`^\d+-[A-Za-z].+(?=[\d] ).`
and figure out it by yourself.

Comment: But your expression gives 8 matches in 115157 steps and does not properly match the messages... Did you use original OP's text to match? There's link https://regex101.com/r/1P0MAJ/1

Comment: @Cromax. **First** after I put the picture the guys **update** their answer. I took this picture just to show. **Second** This person what to learn and I said in a simple way. Otherwise I can make it less than. **Third** your link is empty. **Fourth** thank you :)

Comment: My appreciation for your effort to teach anybody new stuff, seriously. I probably missed you were just about to explain positive lookaheads and not to provide working solution. As to the link — that's strange, 'cos here it actually works. I updated it again (note version 2 at the end): https://regex101.com/r/1P0MAJ/2 But if it doesn't work again, then don't bother it's actually not worth it.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to play around with this. I came up with a way to do it based off of Faibbus's comment, but this is useful and I need to come up with another expression that is very similar, so i'll try this.

Comment: @Matt Just play with it and do not worry after a few month you get it down